# Help in this easy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

If $C$ is a curve with genus $g$ and $k$ a field, I'm stuck in something I'm sure easy, I think I'm forgetting some basic things.

Define $\Omega(D)=\{\omega\in\Omega;div(\omega)\ge D\}$ and $\delta(D)=\dim_k(\Omega(D))$. I'm trying to prove this equivalence:

> There is a diferencial $w$ with $\text{ord}_P(w)=n-1\ \Leftrightarrow
>  \delta((n-1)P)=1+\delta(nP)$

In another words:

> There is a diferencial $w$ with $\text{ord}_P(w)=n-1\ \Leftrightarrow
>  \dim_k(\Omega((n-1)P))=1+\dim_k(\Omega(nP))$

I'm studying Fulton's Algebraic Curves [book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I couldn't prove this equivalence.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first make a trivial but useful remark: $\Omega(nP)\subseteq\Omega((n-1)P)$.

Now, suppose that $\delta((n-1)P)=1+\delta(nP)$. Thus, there must exists $w$ such that $w\in\Omega((n-1)P), w \notin\Omega(nP)$. This implies that $div(w)\geq (n-1)P$ and $ord_{P}(w)<n$, hence $ord_{P}(w)=n-1$. We have proved the first implication.

Suppose now that there exists such $w$. This means that $\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\geq 1$. We want to prove that $\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\leq 1$. Using Riemann-Roch, we have:

$0\leq l(nP)-l((n-1)P)=\delta(nP)+n+1-g-\delta((n-1)P)-(n-1)-1+g=\delta(nP)-\delta((n-1)P)+1\Rightarrow\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\leq1$

and we have finished.

Comment: Great answer, can you just explain in the fifth line why the fact $ord_P(w)=n-1$ is equivalent to $\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\ge 1$? thank you very much!

Comment: Sure: for the initial remark you know that $\Omega(nP)\subseteq\Omega((n-1)P)$, thus $\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\geq 0$ and it's 0 if and only if $\Omega(nP)=Omega((n-1)P)$. But you know also that $w\in\Omega((n-1)P), w\notin\Omega(nP)$, hence you can conclude $\delta((n-1)P)-\delta(nP)\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much again!!! you helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have another question, why $w\in \Omega((n-1)P)$, $w\notin \Omega(nP)$? what I know is $ord_P(w)=n-1$, but I don't know anything about the other points. We have to have $ord_Q(w)\ge 0$ for $Q\neq P$ and we don't if this is true.

Comment: What you know is that $div(w)=(n-1)P+Q$ where $Q\geq 0$ because $w$ is a holomorphic differential. This means that $div(w)-(n-1)P=Q\geq 0$ but $div(w)-nP=Q-P\notgeq 0$.

Comment: yes, you're right I didn't notice the differential was holomorphic.